# rails assets image not find after enalble apache x-sendfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, assets, x-sendfile

I've a problem in my website. It's made using:

- ruby 1.9.3
- rails 3.2.9
- and it's hosted by apache 2 server.

The server worked fine, but yesterday i apport a change in my code.
i needed to add a big files downloader and for this i used the apache module: `x-sendfile`.
when i configured it, the download operation had no problem. But when this module is enabled the site's images have not to show

I see that the problem start when i enable the module in my `config/enviorment/production.rb` file by adding the row:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

The probem is that rails command image_tag("it.png") search file in `/assets/it.png` without find it.

I think that it's a problem with assets pipeline configuration.

This is my `config/enviorments/production.rb` file:

```
IdePro::Application.configure do
    # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

    # Code is not reloaded between requests
    config.cache_classes = false  

    # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
    config.consider_all_requests_local = true 
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false  

    # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
    config.serve_static_assets = false

    # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
    config.assets.compress = true

    # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
    config.assets.compile = false

    #config.assets.precompile += ['logo.png']

    # Generate digests for assets URLs
    config.assets.digest = true

    # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
    # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

    # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
    config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
    # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

    # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure    cookies.
    # config.force_ssl = true

    # See everything in the log (default is :info)
    # config.log_level = :debug

    # Use a different logger for distributed setups
    # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

    # Use a different cache store in production
    # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

    # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
    # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

    # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
    # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

    # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
    # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

    # Enable threaded mode
    # config.threadsafe!

    # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
    # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true

    # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
image_tag(image_path('it.png'))
```